# How to clear Jupyter Notebook's output in all cells from the Linux terminal?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a problem when the output from a notebook is really long and it's saved into the notebook, any time I want to open this particular notebook again the browser crashes and can't display correctly.

To fix this I have to open it with a text editor and delete all output from that cell causing the problem.

I wonder if there is a way to clean all output from the notebook so one can open it again without problem. I want to delete all output since deleting a specific one seems more troublesome.

Comment: minrk created a script for that. See https://gist.github.com/minrk/6176788.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

**nbconvert 6.0 should fix `--clear-output`**

The option had been broken for a long time previously, bug report with merged patch: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/822

Usage should be for in-place operation:

```
jupyter nbconvert --clear-output --inplace my_notebook.ipynb
```

Or to save to another file called `my_notebook_no_out.ipynb`:

```
jupyter nbconvert --clear-output \
  --to notebook --output=my_notebook_no_out my_notebook.ipynb
```

This was brought to my attention [by Harold in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908319/how-to-clear-an-ipython-notebooks-output-in-all-cells-from-the-linux-terminal/47774393?noredirect=1#comment111956519_47774393).

**Before nbconvert 6.0: `--ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True`**

Same usage as `--clear-output`:

```
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --inplace my_notebook.ipynb
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True \
  --to notebook --output=my_notebook_no_out my_notebook.ipynb
```

Tested in Jupyter 4.4.0, notebook==5.7.6.

Comment: This will convert the notebook to html, which does not seem to be what the op wants..

Comment: @Jacquot What version of Jupyter are you in? I have just re-tested and it modifies the `.ipynb` inplace without creating HTML.

Comment: I read too quickly your comment and didn't know the `--inplace` option ; I learned something. But it appears for my version 5.3.1, the option `--clear-output` is available, that summarizes `--ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --inplace`

Comment: I had to add a `--to notebook` to make the second version (non-inplace) work

Comment: @olejorgenb thanks for the report. Can you also give your ipython version and explain what happens if you don't give `--to notebook`? I will test this out later.

Comment: @olejorgenb OK, it was saving as HTML, updated answer.

Comment: The option `--clear-output` was broken, see issue [#822](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/822). This has been fixed last month (July 2020) so it should work again in the next release.

Comment: with `jupyter core: 4.7.1, jupyter-notebook : 6.2.0, qtconsole: 5.0.2, ipython          : 7.20.0, ipykernel: 5.4.3, jupyter client   : 6.1.11, jupyter lab : not installed, nbconvert : 5.6.1, ipywidgets: 6.0.0, nbformat: 5.1.2, traitlets: 5.0.5`
only `jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --inplace my_notebook.ipynb` is working for me

Comment: If the notebook was not saved before running this, will it overwrite any unsaved changes?

Comment: @AustinWolff if it was not saved then presumably it will remove whatever output is on disk which is all it can see? And then when you save if it has output it will overwrite existing file and contain output? Let me know if you test otherwise.

Answer (score 60):

If you create a `.gitattributes` [file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), you can run a filter over certain files before they are added to git.  This will leave the original file on disk as-is, but commit the "cleaned" version.

For this to work, add this to your local `.git/config` or global `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[filter "strip-notebook-output"]
    clean = "jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --to=notebook --stdin --stdout --log-level=ERROR"
```

Then create a `.gitattributes` file in your directory with notebooks, with this
content:

```
*.ipynb filter=strip-notebook-output
```

How this works:

- The attribute tells git to run the filter's `clean` action on each notebook file before adding it to the index (staging).
- The filter is our friend `nbconvert`, set up to read from stdin, write to stdout, strip the output, and only speak when it has something important to say.
- When a file is extracted from the index, the filter's `smudge` action is run, but this is a no-op as we did not specify it.  You could run your notebook here to re-create the output (`nbconvert --execute`).
- Note that if the filter somehow fails, the file will be staged unconverted.

My only minor gripe with this process is that I can commit `.gitattributes` but I have to tell my co-workers to update their `.git/config`.

If you want a hackier but much faster version, try [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
  clean = "jq '.cells[].outputs = [] | .cells[].execution_count = null | .'"
```

Comment: this is the best of both worlds. Thanks for sharing this

Comment: Didn’t know about this. This is super-useful.

Comment: A slightly improved alternative is as follows. It cleans the metadata, and doesn't add outputs and execution_count to non code cells like the proposed JQ solution (which results in a warning):
`clean = "jq '.cells |= map(if .\"cell_type\" == \"code\" then .outputs = [] | .execution_count = null else . end | .metadata = {}) | .metadata = {}'"`

Comment: As a final step, you probably want to scrub and recommit all of your existing notebooks, otherwise you could get heinous merge conflicts later. To do that run `git add --renormalize .` and then commit.

Answer (score 11):

Use **--ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True** and **--clear-output**

Following this command:

`jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --clear-output *.ipynb`

Answer (score 11):

`nbstripout` worked well for me.

Open the Jupyter terminal, navigate to the folder containing your notebook, and then run the following line:

`nbstripout my_notebook.ipynb`

Comment: Excellent - or even `nbstripout *.ipynb` :)

Comment: Might be obvious for most, but you need to first install nbstripout with something like: pip install nbstripout

Answer (score 7):

To extend the answer from @dirkjot to resolve issue regarding sharing configuration:

Create a local .gitconfig file, rather than modifying .git/config. This makes the command that needs to be run on other machines slightly simpler. You can also create a script to run the `git config` command:

git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig

Note I have also changed the log level to INFO because I did want to see confirmation that the clean was running.

**repo/.gitconfig**

```
[filter "strip-notebook-output"]
    clean = "jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --to=notebook --stdin --stdout --log-level=INFO"
```

**repo/.gitattributes**

```
*.ipynb filter=strip-notebook-output
```

**repo/git_configure.sh**

```
git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig
```

Users then just need to run:

```
$ chmod u+x git_configure.sh
$ ./git_configure.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [clean_ipynb](https://github.com/KwatME/clean_ipynb), which not only clears notebook output but can also clean the code.

Install by `pip install clean_ipynb`

Run by `clean_ipynb hello.ipynb`

Comment: [nbclean](https://github.com/choldgraf/nbclean) is a tool that can do that with some handy additional features, such as only removing only certain blocks of code/text,  that make it handy for use for teaching.

Answer (score 4):

I must say I find `jupyer nbconvert` painfully slow for the simple job of clearing some sub-arrays and resetting some execution numbers. It’s a superior solution in maintainability because that tool is expected to be updated if there is a change in the notebook source code format. However, the alternate solution below is faster and may also be useful if you don’t have nbconvert 6.0 (I have an environment running 5.6.1 at the moment…)

A very simple [`jq` (a sort of sed for json)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) script does the trick very fast:

```bash
jq 'reduce path(.cells[]|select(.cell_type == "code")) as $cell (.; setpath($cell + ["outputs"]; []) | setpath($cell + ["execution_count"]; null))' notebook.ipynb > out-notebook.ipynb
```

Very simply, it identifies code cells, and replaces their `outputs` and `execution_count` attributes with `[]` and `null` respectively.

---

Or if you only want to remove the outputs and keep execution numbers, you can do even simpler:

```
jq 'del(.cells[]|select(.cell_type == "code").outputs[])' notebook.ipynb > out-notebook.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the previous answers you can use the command-line json processor `jq` to perform this task notably quicker than with `nbconvert`. A complete command for getting rid of metadata, outputs and execution counts can be found in this [blog post](https://timstaley.co.uk/posts/making-git-and-jupyter-notebooks-play-nice/):

```
jq --indent 1 \
    '
    (.cells[] | select(has("outputs")) | .outputs) = []
    | (.cells[] | select(has("execution_count")) | .execution_count) = null
    | .metadata = {"language_info": {"name":"python", "pygments_lexer": "ipython3"}}
    | .cells[].metadata = {}
    ' 01-parsing.ipynb
```

If desired, you could modify to just clean a specific part of the output, such as execution counts (recursively wherever they occur in the json), and then add this as a git filter:

```
[filter "nbstrip"]
    clean = jq --indent 1 '(.. |."execution_count"? | select(. != null)) = null'
    smudge = cat
```

And add the following to `~/.config/git/attributes` to have the filter applied globally to all your local repos:

```
*.ipynb filter=nbstripout
```

There is also [nbstripout](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout) which is made for this purpose, but it's a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `pre-commit` approach, using something like:

```
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: jupyter-nb-clear-output
        name: jupyter-nb-clear-output
        files: \.ipynb$
        stages: [commit]
        language: python
        entry: jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --inplace
        additional_dependencies: ['jupyterlab']
```

also explained more in [this blog](https://zhauniarovich.com/post/2020/2020-06-clearing-jupyter-output/).

Comment: This update reminds me that there's also a GitHub action for cleaning notebooks, too. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/notebook-to-github/7657/3?u=fomightez).

Comment: when I do it this way on Github Desktop, I get the following error: 
"jupyter-nb-clear-output..................................................Failed
- hook id: jupyter-nb-clear-output
- exit code: 1

Executable `jupyter` not found"

Comment: does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found) help?

Answer (score 0):

Parse the json:

```
#LARGE Notebook Clean Make a Copy FIRST and Run this only on the COPY!!!!

import json 
filename = 'COPY_of_Huge_Notebook.ipynb' 
f = open(filename) 
large_ntbk = json.load(f) 
f.close() 
outputs = large_ntbk['cells'] 
for o in outputs:
    if 'outputs' in o:
        outputs['outputs'] = []

small = open('small.ipynb', 'w') 
json.dump(large_ntbk, small, indent = 2) 
small.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my homebrew solution that I used from within a notebook to clear the 200MB output from another notebook:

```py
with open('input.ipynb', 'r') as input_file, open('output.ipynb', 'w') as output_file:
    outblock=False 
    s2 = '   ],\n'
    s0 = '   "outputs": [],\n'
    s1 = '   "outputs": [\n'
    
    for line in input_file:
        if outblock:
            if line == s2:
                print(f'match{s2[:-1]}')
                outblock = False
                output_file.write(s0)
            continue     
        if line == s0:
            print(f'match{s0[:-1]}')
            output_file.write(line)
            continue
        if line == s1:
            print(f'match{s1[:-1]}')
            outblock = True
            continue
        output_file.write(line)
```