# Keyboard shortcut to clear cell output in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know what is the keyboard shortcut to clear (not toggle) the cell output in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I raised an issue: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1925

Comment: Warning! `Esc + d + d` deletes the cell!

Comment: If you don't mind loosing the other outputs as well, you can try Edit/Clear all outputs method. For example it might to be useful before committing a notebook from colab to github.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can setup your own shortcut in the UI (for the latest master version):

[image]

This menu can be found in `Help > Keyboard Shortcuts` in any open notebook.

Comment: Specifically, this is under `Help > Edit Keyboard Shortcuts` in any open notebook.

Comment: Great suggestions above. I personally like to clean the output from CLI so thought would share that info here as well

`jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --inplace Notebook.ipynb`

More info --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908319/how-to-clear-an-ipython-notebooks-output-in-all-cells-from-the-linux-terminal

Comment: This option is not there in Jupyter Lab

Comment: This is in Jupyter notebook. Anything similar in Jupyterlab?

Answer (score 76):

For versions less than 5:

#### Option 1 -- quick hack:

Change the cell type to raw then back to code: <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> will discard the output.

#### Option 2 -- custom shortcut (without GUI):

For this, you need to edit the `custom.js` file which is typically located at `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` (if it doesn't exist, create it).

In there, you have to add

```js
require(['base/js/namespace']) {
    // setup 'ctrl-l' as shortcut for clearing current output
    Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts
           .add_shortcut('ctrl-l', 'jupyter-notebook:clear-cell-output');
}
```

You can add shortcut there for all the fancy things you like, since the 2nd argument can be a function ([docs](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html))

If you want mappings for other standard commands, you can dump a list of all available commands by running the following in your notebook:

```
from IPython.core.display import Javascript

js = """
  var jc_html = "";
  var jc_array = Object.keys(IPython.notebook.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.actions._actions);
  for (var i=0;i<jc_array.length;i++) {
    jc_html = jc_html + jc_array[i] + "<br >";
  }
  element.html(jc_html);
  """

Javascript(data=js, lib=None, css=None)
```

Answer (score 20):

Add following at start of cell and run it:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
clear_output(wait=True)
```

Comment: Useful if you want to run the cell without removing all the print commands.

Answer (score 14):

Adding for **JupyterLab** users. *Ctrl,* or *Cmd,* (advanced settings) and pasting the below in User References under keyboard shortcuts does the trick for me.

```
{
"shortcuts": [
        {
            "command": "notebook:hide-cell-outputs",
            "keys": [
                "H"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
        },
        {
            "command": "notebook:show-cell-outputs",
            "keys": [
                "Shift H"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time :D

Comment: @ИльяМитусов super glad to hear it! I just dropped my current key bindings into [this](https://github.com/GEM7318/JupyterLab-Custom/blob/master/KeyBindings.txt) repo in case they're helpful and will keep it up to date as best I can.

Comment: This is the third time in maybe 3-5 years I've found myself back at this answer to this question after googling "command clear cell output jupyter lab". I really appreciate the awareness users like you bring to these Q/A's that the question asker's needs often don't reflect everyone's who come here.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Help` -> `Edit Keyboard Shortcuts`.

[image]

Then add the Shortcut you desire to the "Clear Cell" field.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Depends if you consider the **command palette** a short-cut. I do.

1. Press 'control-shift-p', that opens the command palette.
2. Then type 'clear cell output'. That will let you select the command to clear the output.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To delete/clear individual cell outputs in JupyterLab (without going to Edit > Clear Output), go to `Settings > Advanced Settings Editor (Ctrl+,) > Keyboard Shortcuts` and add this to "shortcuts":

```
{
  "command": "notebook:clear-cell-output",
  "keys": [
    "Shift D",
    "Shift D"
  ],
  "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
}
```

And save it! (Ctrl + S)

Then when you are in the editor, just press Esc to escape the edit mode and press Shift + d + d.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the command line:
`jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --inplace *.ipynb`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a keyboard shortcut but to clear all output you can click the following buttons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just looked and found cell|all output|clear which worked with:

Server Information:
You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is: 6.1.5
The server is running on this version of Python:
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]

Current Kernel Information:
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.