# Jupyter notebook shortcut to uncomment

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I know that the keyboard shortcut to comment code in jupyter notebook is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

But, what is the shortcut to uncomment code?

This question is interesting, but I cant find shortcut for uncomment.
[keyboard shortcut to clear cell output in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924826/keyboard-shortcut-to-clear-cell-output-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: should be the same?

Comment: George thanks for answering. Yes CTRL+/ is a toggle for comment and uncomment!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

CTRL+/ is a toggle for comment and uncomment! Thanks George for the answer...

Comment: For Opera users: The CMD+"/" shortcut is preset for calling "Help" in the browser window, so if you want to use CMD+"/" for Jupyter, you must disable it in Opera under Settings | Advanced | Keyboard Shortcuts > scroll down to "Help" (below "Downloads" entry) and delete the shortcut. Restart Opera.

Comment: For Mac users: I found out that the CMD+"/" shortcut is also preset on OSX systemwide! So you must deactivate that under System Preferences | Keyboard | Shortcuts | App Shortcuts > uncheck "Show Help menu" entry

Comment: I use ctrl + # key on my chromebook (in python kernel) to toggle comments