# Notebook validation failed: Non-unique cell id 'hawaiian-pregnancy' detected. Corrected to '8fbbc816'.:

Tags: jupyter

i have copied the notebook to create another version and all the time getting this strange errors, Does anyone have a clue how to get rid of it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66746193/notebook-validation-failed-jupyter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved it with clicking "Trust" in jupyter notebook on the tool panel.

Answer (score 1):

The best temporary solution so far is the following, from [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6001#issuecomment-959828688) GitHub issue:

> First select all the cells in the Jupyter Notebook, then press the "cut/scissors" button (don't panic, at this point your Notebook will be empty), and finally press the "paste" button.