# How to load a jupyter-notebook without executing the cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to give a Jupyter-Notebook demo showing new users various features of JN plus my codes.  I have written out my presentation as a Jupyter Notebook.  But when I load my prepared notebook, all the cells are executed/evaluated.

Q:  How can I load my prepared notebook without executing/evaluating any cell (and let me do so one by one)?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to my own question:  After finish composing the notebook, clear the output of all executable cells -- cf for example

[Keyboard shortcut to clear cell output in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924826/keyboard-shortcut-to-clear-cell-output-in-jupyter-notebook)

for a neat keyboard shortcut, and then save the notebook.  Next time you fire up the notebook, you can run the cells one by one!  This does not affect the markdown cells, which is what I need.