# Clear a specific metadata property of a Jupyter Notebook in version control

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

When saving my jupyter Notebooks with Git, I'd like to remove:

- Outputs (answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004619/3733974)
- `ExecuteTime` in metadata (code below in `.ipynb`)

  ```
   "metadata": {
    "ExecuteTime": {
     "end_time": "2020-07-09T11:09:35.842718Z",
     "start_time": "2020-07-09T11:09:35.837714Z"
    },
    "tags": [
     "parameters"
    ]
   }
  ```

I am able to remove all the metadata with `--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True` but I want to **remove only `ExecuteTime` metadata**.

How to update my current command in `.git/config`?

```
[filter "strip-notebook-output"]
    clean = "jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True --to=notebook --stdin --stdout --log-level=ERROR"
```

How to pass arguments to [ClearMetadataPreprocessor](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/preprocessors.html#nbconvert.preprocessors.ClearMetadataPreprocessor)?

Comment: Unfortunately the ClearMetadataPreprocessor does not have any more options than to remove all the metadata. See also the pull request for this feature https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/pull/805

Comment: You can also use `jq` for this, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74104683/2166823

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `preserve_cell_metadata_mask` option of the `ClearMetadataPreprocessor`. As far as I can tell, this feature was [added](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/pull/1314) in nbconvert v6.0.

Quote from `jupyter nbconvert --help-all`:

> --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_cell_metadata_mask=<set-item-1>...
> Indicates the key paths to preserve when deleting metadata across both cells
> and notebook metadata fields. Tuples of keys can be passed to preserved
> specific nested values
> Default: set()

For the OP example the command should be like this:

```
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True \
--ClearMetadataPreprocessor.preserve_cell_metadata_mask='[("tags")]' \
--to=notebook --stdin --stdout --log-level=ERROR
```