# VS Code Jupyter Notebooks are not working, background is turning grey, and I cannot see the output

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have had a problem with VS code for about a week now. I have tried to fix it but no success.

The box that contains the VS code is surrounded with 'grey' color and I cannot see the output (see picture below). I keep having the error message 'Windows does not open'

[image]

[image]
I have tried to:

- copy the code and paste in another script
- install the latest version of VS code
- unable the gpu

All these actions did not help fix the problem. and I am not able to save any output.

Another information that might help is that the size of the jupyter notebook is 500 MB which is huge (another script which have the same code but I did run very rarely has much smaller size). I think my VS code is caching the information and I don't know how to delete the cache.

Comment: I don't see any stuff grey and your shown code has 0 (zero) output

Comment: sorry I added some clarifications. It is around the box that is greyed. Not inside the box. I cannot see the output

Comment: delete all the output blocks with images, I don't expect you typed 500MB Python code, Consider using the Python Interactive  way with `#%%` separators

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my VS jupyter notebook was storing my outputs (i use a lot of print('') ) in almost all boxes which made the size of the `.ipynb` close to 500 000 KB.

The solution is to move the corrupt jupyter notebook outside of the VS code root file. Then open a fresh `.ipynb` file and copy the code from the old (corrupt) to the new jupyter notebook file.

Comment: Do you have a lot of `.ipynb` files to 'fix' in the way you describe there? You can do this programmatically. An outline of the approach is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74394583/8508004). See the comments, too, because what I suggested wasn't exactly what ended up being used. Obviously this could be adapted to be more automated, too.