# is there a command to clear all output when running the notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook, typically I use the menu to clear all output. I am wondering if there is a command (majic command or lines of code) which I can place on the first cell and it will clear all output when running the notebook?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear Jupyter Notebook's output in all cells from the Linux terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908319/how-to-clear-jupyter-notebooks-output-in-all-cells-from-the-linux-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
clear_output()
```

or

you can use the `%clear` magic command in a code cell

https://nocomplexity.com/documents/jupyterlab/ipython-magiccommands.html

Comment: Thanks Prudhviuraj, your two suggestions only clear the output in that sepcific cell.  My goal is to clear all outputs in all cells. so it doesn't work for my way. Other solutions? Thanks