# Force Jupyter Notebook not to store cached rendered figures into *.ipynb

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Typically, I use Jupyter notebook to make documentation of numerical math in my projects on github. I consider writing python code which generates figures *on-the-fly* as very economical way how to store figures. Also git can version-control the python code much more efficiently than binary data of rendered figures.

```
# initialize environment
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sy
x = np.linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
dx = x[1]-x[0]

# some markdown doc
# then plot figures

a = (1.0-x**2)
b = (x-2)**2  
plt.plot(x,a,label='a')
plt.plot(x,b,label='b')
plt.plot(x,a*b,lw=2,c='k',label='c')
vmax=1.00; plt.ylim(-vmax,vmax); plt.xlim(0.0,4.0); plt.grid(); plt.legend()
```

Now I realized that `*.ipynb` files which I pushed to github contains huge strings encoding rendered figures as images like this:

`"data": {
      "image/png": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAiUAAAFkCAYAAAD....`

I would like to force Jupyter not to do that.

**EDIT:**

as mentioned in comments underneath there are two ways:

1. In web GUI got to `Cell > All Output > Clear`, then save
2. Or use [simple python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178118/how-can-i-open-an-ipython-notebook-without-the-output) to do the same

but the problem is that neither of this method is automatic, so it is very easy to forgot and *commit to git* notebook including the images. It would be very helpfull to have an option to save just striped version of the notebook automatically.

Comment: Clear the output of the cells with plots before you save and push?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178118/how-can-i-open-an-ipython-notebook-without-the-output) may be of interest here.

Comment: ok, both ways work fine, but if I really want to use it as *notebook* for making quick notes, I would like to make it automatic, since I always forgot to clean it before pushing